# can I merge audio (audio location "res - raw - audio.mp3" ) when recording?

Tags: java, android, merge, android-ffmpeg, mp4parser

I will develop an android application to combine video and audio recordings (audio as the background sound of the recording), I have read some ffmpeg and mp4parser references, can anyone help me?

Comment: i think you want to merge and audio and video together. right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to make an application like you need. The source code will be huge, so I can give you a description of an algorithm and some useful links.

**Video:**
You need to record a video using [the camera 2 api](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface). This Surface should be gotten from [MediaCodec (encoder)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec). The MediaCodec (encoder) will [encode video frames](https://github.com/PhilLab/Android-MediaCodec-Examples/blob/master/EncodeAndMuxTest.java) from a camera and convert them into ByteBuffers.

**Audio:**
You need to extract an audio from your raw file using [MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor) which will extract audio samples as ByteBuffers.

**Muxing:**
Both, audio samples (ByteBuffers) and video frames (ByteBuffers) should be muxed using [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer).

Comment: thank you so much, is there an SDK that has provided it all, so, I just call the function

Comment: @keen all these classes provided by Android SDK

Comment: @keen if you found my answer useful, please add a vote for it